# injecting JPA entityManager via @PersistenceContext

Tags: jpa, thread-safety, entitymanager

I've read that the entityManger injected by Spring via @PersistenceContext is threadsafe, can anyone confirm this?  anyone had thread issue with it? I'm a little concerned (see my dao class below.) Our app is a Spring-mvc/JPA/hibernate webapp.  The web requests are pretty straight forward, each request does only one of the CRUD operations, we are not creating any threads on our own in the CRUD processing logics.

Here's how we have it wired.

hibernate persistence xml

`<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
   ..... //snipped`

Spring context xml

```
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

</bean>
```

DAO implemenation class -- this is a singleton Spring injected bean.  Because it's a singleton, I'm a little concerned having entityManager as an instance variable

```
@Repository
@Configurable
public class NotificationDaoImpl implements NotificationDao {
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

    public void someSave(Entity someEntity) {
       em.merge(someEntity);
    }
```

sample entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
@Configurable
public class SomeEntity {
```

Comment: Yes, of course it's thread-safe. But why do you ask such a question? Why would you believe me if you don't believe the official Spring documentation? Spring is used in thousands of server-side applications. Don't you think they would have noticed if their EntityManager was not thread-safe?

Comment: main reason for my concern is that we had a very-hard-to-find-thread bug related to instance variable in Spring singleton bean, so I'm being extra cautious.